# how to hide an id from a joomla url

Tags: php, joomla, router

i have installed a compoenet from that it generates url like this

```
 http://localhost/index.php/home/abc?id=23
```

i want to hide the id from that url. is there any posibility to pass the id but not visible on url ?

Comment: Is abc required to be unique?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your site Global configuration > site tab > SEO Settings > Enalble Adds Suffix to URL option and save

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly on Joomla 3.1.5 and 3.2.
Edit "components/com_content/router.php"

There are two places need to do change, one near the top, one in the middle
Replace this:

```
  $advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 0);
```

With this:

```
  $advanced = $params->get('sef_advanced_link', 1);

  - From: ->where($db->quoteName(‘alias’) . ‘ = ‘ . 
  $db->quote($db->quote($segment)));
  - To: ->where($db->quoteName(‘alias’) . ‘ = ‘ . $db->quote($segment));
```

Hopefully help you.